# Find all functions such that $ (\int _0 ^1 xf(x) dx)^3 = \frac{4}{25} \int _0 ^1 f(x)^3 dx$

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

Calculate all the functions $f \in L^3$ such that

$$ \left(\int _0 ^1 xf(x) dx\right)^3 = \frac{4}{25} \int _0 ^1 f(x)^3 dx$$

Can someone please walk me through this because there are no such examples in the book.

Comment: Is $g$ anything in particular?

Comment: sorry writing error

Comment: Use integration by parts on the left side.

Comment: Do not try to blank out your question. It won't work.

Answer (score 4):

Using the Holder inequality, we have
$$
\left(\int_0^1 |x\,f(x)|\,dx\right)^3
\leq \left(\int_0^1 x^{3/2}\,dx\right)^2 \left(\int_0^1 |f(x)|^3\,dx\right)
= \frac{4}{25} \int_0^1 |f(x)|^3\,dx.
$$
But from our equation above we know this must be an equality.  The Holder inequality is sharp exactly when one function is a constant multiple of the other, so we conclude that $f(x) = cx$ for some $c\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Very clever, can I just clerafy something for myself holder yells that $a|f|^p= b |g|^q$ so we have that $x^{3/2}=cf(x)^3$ so when we take the third root we have that $f(x)=c \sqrt{x}$

Comment: Holder says that $\|fg\|_{L^1} \leq \|f\|_{L^p}\|g\|_{L^{p'}}$ where $p' = \frac{p}{p-1}$ and $1\leq p\leq \infty$  In this case $g = x$, $p=3$, $p'=3/2$, and both sides were cubed.